# Is it possible to create this shape with css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I was wondering how could I make this shape wit css and css only, thanks in advance.

[image: shape]

Comment: What did you try? Please before asking any question, give a little effort into solving it first and mentioning the steps.

Comment: With clip-path support is limited https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into this.

```css
div {
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 79%, 60% 78%, 78% 100%, 0 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 79%, 60% 78%, 78% 100%, 0 100%);
background:red;
height:80px;
width:100px
}
```

```html
<div><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```css
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 79%, 70% 79%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 79%, 70% 79%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

This is a useful website to create the shapes that you want : 
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```css
.trapz {
  margin: 10px; /* not necessary for the trapezoid */
  width: 300px;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="trapz"> </div>
```